# Python Generating Infinite Loop When First Arg is 0

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am not understanding why the below code is falling into an infinite loop when the 'start' argument of totalArea is 0. I have been watching the code run in Python Tutor, and j executes through value of Stop -1, but then resets to 0 without moving onto value of Stop.

```
import math
def totalArea(start, stop, step):
    def f(x):
        return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

    area = 0.0
    j = start

    while j <= len(range(start, stop)):

        for j in range(start, stop):
            area += float(step) * f(j)

    print area

totalArea(0, 11, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while j <= len(range(start, stop)):
    for j in range(start, stop):
```

Every time the for loop ends, `j = 10`

`len(range(start, stop))` is `11`

So `j <= len(range(start, stop))` forever

The `while` loop seems entirely superfluous. Try removing it entirely:

```
def totalArea(start, stop, step):
    def f(x):
        return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

    area = 0.0
    j = start

    for j in range(start, stop):
        area += float(step) * f(j)

    print area
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the outer (while) loop, len(range(start,stop) is a constant (11).  Within the inner (for) loop, j takes on the values 0 to 10 (per the help for range:

```
Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
    range(i, j) returns [i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1]
```

)

Why not take out the outer while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `start=0` and `stop=11`. Then `len(range(start,stop))` is 11, the length of `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. Inside the `while` loop, `j` iterates over the values 0 through 10. As you can see, `j` never exceeds 11, so the `while` loop never terminates.

Answer (score 0):

The range function returns a list that doesn't include the end value:

```
>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```